# Dynamically Generate Set of RadioButtons With Different Content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, radio-button

I am a C++ developer and recently shifted to C#. I am working on a WPF app where I need to dynamically generate 4 radio buttons. I tried to do lot of RnD but looks like this scenario is rare.

**XAML:**

```
<RadioButton Content="Base 0x" Height="16" Name="radioButton1" Width="80" />
```

Now here is the scenario: I should generate this radio button 4 times with different `Content` as follows:

```
<RadioButton Content = Base 0x0 />
<RadioButton Content = Base 0x40 />
<RadioButton Content = Base 0x80 />
<RadioButton Content = Base 0xc0 />
```

I had done this in my C++ application as follows:

```
#define MAX_FPGA_REGISTERS 0x40;

for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    m_registerBase[i] = new ToggleButton(String(T("Base 0x")) + String::toHexString(i * MAX_FPGA_REGISTERS));       
    addAndMakeVisible(m_registerBase[i]);
    m_registerBase[i]->addButtonListener(this);
}
m_registerBase[0]->setToggleState(true);
```

If you notice above, Every-time for loop runs Content name becomes `Base 0x0`, `Base 0x40`, `base 0x80` and `base 0xc0` and sets the toggle state of first radiobutton as true. Thus if you notice there will be single button click method for all these 4 buttons and based on index each will perform operation.

How can i achieve this in my WPF app? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was going to write a set of code for you, but realized your question is probably already answered here: 
[WPF/C# - example for programmatically create & use Radio Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623689/wpf-c-example-for-programmatically-create-use-radio-buttons)

It's probably the cleanest way of doing it, depending on your requirements of course. If you want the simplest case, here it is:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid >
        <StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton() { Content = "Radio button " + i, IsChecked = i == 0  };
            rb.Checked += (sender, args) => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Pressed " + ( sender as RadioButton ).Tag );
            };
            rb.Unchecked += (sender, args) => { /* Do stuff */ };
            rb.Tag = i;

            MyStackPanel.Children.Add( rb );
        }
    }
```

Just add in whatever logic you need for the content, tags and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy :) MVVM is the aproach i would like to take. But I can see he has a 2 button click events. Is that required in my MVVM approach?

Comment: No it isn't required. I would also like to point out that the event handlers are added in a "non-MVVM" way, as they are set in the window's code-behind rather than through XAML and the view model. What you would instead do is set a binding on the IsChecked property of the radiobutton, using a style.

In any case, you can subscribe to or ignore whatever events you want.

Comment: Well this looks good. I tried to implement the MVVM approach and that looks quiet good. YOur approach is much simpler too :)

Comment: Ideally I would like to have a index with it which gives me whichever radiobutton i have selected. Since the buttonclick method is same for all, ID would help me execute the logic for the particular radiobutton slected. How can I do that in MVVM way? :)

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284752/mvvm-binding-radio-buttons-to-a-view-model

The first answer there should help you if you want to do it purely with MVVM. Otherwise, try my edit of the initialization code above.

Comment: Thanks buddy :) YOu been helpful :)